# How to insert date in SQL Server from any format to datetime format?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a requirement where I need to insert date from any format like mm/dd/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy, yyyy/mm/dd, dd-mm-yyyy to datetime format yyyy-mm-dd.
how to do this?

This is what I tried:

```
declare @date nvarchar(20)
set @date='2018/10/20'
SELECT case when @date=FORMAT(convert(date, @date, 105),'dd-MM-yyyy') 
then (select convert(datetime,convert(date, @date, 105), 105)) 
when @date= FORMAT(convert(date, @date, 103),'dd/MM/yyyy') 
then (select convert(datetime,convert(date, @date, 103), 103))
when @date= FORMAT(convert(date, @date, 110),'MM-dd-yyyy')
then (select convert(datetime,convert(date, @date, 110), 110))
when @date= FORMAT(convert(date, @date, 101),'MM/dd/yyyy')
then (select convert(datetime,convert(date, @date, 101), 101))
when @date= FORMAT(convert(date, @date, 23),'yyyy-MM-dd')
then (select convert(datetime,convert(date, @date, 23), 23))
when @date= FORMAT(convert(date, @date, 111),'yyyy/MM/dd')
then (select convert(datetime,convert(date, @date, 111), 111))
end
```

but it failed when converting `'2018/10/20'` to `'dd/mm/yyyy'` and other irrelevant formats that used in case statement except `'yyyy/MM/dd'`.

Comment: You determine the format in the code doing the inserts, convert it into a proper unambiguous format (ISO) and use that always.

Comment: can you clarify how you can differentiate from mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy? that is, when you're given the data 01/02/2019, how do you know? are they coming from different sources?

Comment: yes, the data comes from different sources where date can be in any format as mentioned in question

Comment: Consider using a parameterized query, passing a strongly-typed date value, where the app parses the date string. Be aware that some date formats are ambiguous ("yyyy-mm-dd" and "yyyy-dd-mm") so it won't always be possible to reliably determine the proper value.

Comment: @DanGuzman  Yes i tried but it didn't worked as per my requirement. pls see the updated question that i have tried.

Comment: @PuranKandpal, a variable is not a parameter. Parameters are passed from application code where the native value (already parsed) is provided.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes. I will put that variable as parameter once the code work successfully.

Comment: Your goal is impossible. There is no logic you can use that will **correctly** identify a date using any possible string format. "12/01/2018" can be either December 1 or January 12. Nothing but the provider of that information can tell you which is correct. Embrace your doom or change your goal.

Comment: @SMor, the parameter will be type date but your variable is varchar.

Answer (score 0):

[CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DECLARE
  @txt1 varchar(10)='12/05/2019', -- mm/dd/yyyy
  @txt2 varchar(10)='05/12/2019', -- dd/mm/yyyy
  @txt3 varchar(10)='2019/12/05', -- yyyy/mm/dd
  @txt4 varchar(10)='05-12-2019' -- dd-mm-yyyy

SELECT
  CONVERT(date,@txt1,101) -- mm/dd/yyyy
  ,CONVERT(date,REPLACE(@txt2,'/','.'),103) -- dd/mm/yyyy
  ,CONVERT(date,@txt3,111) -- yyyy/mm/dd
  ,CONVERT(date,@txt4,105) -- dd-mm-yyyy
```